# How to push powershell command result to json response in NodeJs using Express?

Tags: node.js, powershell, express

How to handle this task?

I need push data from *Powershell.on* event to response some data to a client web page. But I'm not a good programmer. How to do that?:

```
router.all('/', (req, res, next) => {
    var NetbiosName = req.query.hostname.split('.', 1);
    var cmd = "New-ADComputer -Name " +  NetbiosName[0] + " -SamAccountName " + 
    NetbiosName[0]; 
    var gdata;
    let ps = new PowerShell(cmd);
    ps.on("error", err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
    ps.on("output", data => {
      //need to push this data to responce json
      console.log(data);
    });
    ps.on("error-output", data => {
      //need to push this data to responce json
      console.error(data);
    });
    ps.on("end", code => {
    });

    //console.log(ps.send(['help',]));
    res.status(200).json({
      "hostname": req.query.hostname,
      "userclass": req.query.userclass,
      "host": NetbiosName[0],
      "cmd": cmd,
      "data": "Data from ps.on",
    });
    //console.log(util.inspect(req));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a function to send the data back to the client.

   ```
   function sendResponse(data) {
       res.status(200).json({
           "hostname": req.query.hostname,
           "userclass": req.query.userclass,
           "host": NetbiosName[0],
           "cmd": cmd,
           "data": data
       });
   }
   ```
2. Call that function from your declared events *output* and *error-output*

   ```
   ps.on("output", data => {
       sendResponse(data);
   });
   ps.on("error-output", data => {
       sendResponse(data);
   });
   ```